# another's vs another

Tags: pronouns, possessives

> If just a few hundred hours of play-based therapy can improve my life and save **another’s**, I am more than happy to help.

Should I replace "another’s" with "another"?

Comment: You are (hopefully) saving a life belonging to someone else, so the possessive form is correct.

Comment: @Mick Which is possessive

Comment: Actually, I think you can use either. If you use "another", you are just saving "another life". If you use "another's", you are saving "another person's life" (possessive form).

Comment: @VaibhavBajaj We form the possessive in English by appending to a noun what we call the _Saxon genitive:_ an apostrophe followed by the letter "**s**". The possessive here is _another's._

Comment: @Mick I am shocked! Shocked! to hear you intimate that the voting model may be less than rational. Call anathema!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> can improve my life and save another’s

This is mostly a question of style.  "Another" is acceptable as it's short for "another life".  "Another's" is short for "another person's life".  Both mean the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

It seems it does matter depend on the subject as in this line from a Hank Williams song:
"It's hard to know another's lips will kiss you"
It would not be correct to say another lip will kiss you, and the only way it would make sense would be in the possessive.